# Questions on proper REST design

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm designing a REST web-service and have questions on best/proper design.

A search method should be POST, since identical requests don't have to return the same data, right?  Also, is it better to do /search/term or /search and have term as post-var?

Also, what if a resource can be updated at any time, would the method to return it be a GET or  a POST.  It sounds best to be a GET, but since it can change over time, it isn't idempotent.

Comment: You have misunderstood the meaning of idempotence.  I like to use the following rule:  If the user only makes one request and the server receives the same request twice, is that going to have an effect that the user did not expect?  If yes then the request is not idempotent.  In your example, if a user does a GET for a resource and somehow, the server receives the request twice, the end result is that the user is probably  going to see the results of the second request.  From the user's perspective they got back exactly what they asked for, even if it did take a bit longer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not modifying the resource, I would recommend using a GET with the search term in the URL. Cache expiration on the page should be set appropriately (as with all other resources). In this case, you might even want to disable caching entirely.

Comment: Continuing what I said to William Pietri above, I guess that could work for the search method with just the cache disabled.

In theory I could disable cache on other resources, since they can be updated at anytime and have the method to get them be a GET?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a GET with /search/term
To update POST
To create a new something PUT

Comment: You cannot directly correlate POST to update and create to PUT.  PUT can update and create, POST could create, update or do neither.  The behaviour of POST is not defined by the HTTP spec, there are simply suggestions of it is commonly used for what it could be used for.

Comment: @Darrel Miller good point but just like "they are simple suggestions" he answer was simply a "recommend"ation.  8)